# Simple helloworld WebService using asmx not working when published on Windows 2008 R2 IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, asmx

I have a windows 2008 r2 server running IIS 7(Yes it is old this is what is available for me). It has a website running at port 8080.

I have created an Empty Template ASP.NET web application. Then I added new item named Phones.asmx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace OSS_network
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Phones
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

    public class Phones : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string Phonebook()
        {
            return "PhoneBook";
        }
    }
}
```

Then i published it to a folder which contents i copied to a folder on the Win2008 server. In IIS I created a new Website on port 8080 and the path linking to the folder where the published files are located.

I am able to connect to Phones.asmx from the local machine(the server itself) and view methods as well as call them.

Then I try to connect to Phones.asmx remotely which is succesful. I can see the defined WebMethods,
[image]

BUT

when I try to call the method I get the following error:

[image]

Can someone help out with this error? It must be some thing simple.

Answer (score 1):

I have the answer because I good samaritan answered in my last question which got closed down because of not enough information.

I use following line of code to fix this problem. Write the following code in web.config file.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps the next person in trouble like mine.